# CSS/JS) Move Viewport on the right side of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I want to make website like this.

There is a body whose width is much longer than the Viewport's.
Viewport should be on the right side of the screen from the beginning without user's control.

I can only use HTML, CSS and JS because server doesn't let me use neither PHP nor others.
How can I make it with CSS or Javascript?

Comment: check the float property of CSS.. float: right

Comment: @AbdulJabbar `@viewport { float : right ; }` like this?

Comment: don't know what you're doing with meta but normally you'd do it with the viewport element's id.. if it's id is v then #v{float: right}

Answer (score 0):

You could simply scroll by JS.

```
$('body').scrollLeft($(document).outerWidth());
```

**[DEMO](http://liveweave.com/DB4IZb)**

```js
/* Write JavaScript here */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').scrollLeft($(document).outerWidth());
});
$("button").click(function() {
  $('body').scrollLeft($(document).outerWidth());
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 4000px;
}
.box {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>ScrolltoEnd</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
  <div class="box">I'm the End</div>
</div>
```